# npm removing dependencies on each install

Tags: npm

Every time I install a package, node removes a dependency. I am currently on NPM version 6.13.4. I saw that this issue was noted in 2017 on github and it didn't appear to be resolved. Is there a limit to the number of packages I can install? Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www",
    "devstart": "nodemon ./bin/www -e js, pug",
    "serverstart": "DEBUG=test:* npm run devstart"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "async": "^3.2.0",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.762.0",
    "bcrypt": "^4.0.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "connect-redis": "^4.0.4",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.5",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "~4.16.1",
    "express-session": "^1.17.0",
    "express-socket.io-session": "^1.3.5",
    "express-validator": "^6.4.0",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "geojson": "^0.5.0",
    "http": "0.0.1-security",
    "http-errors": "~1.6.3",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.9.7",
    "morgan": "~1.9.1",
    "multer": "^1.4.2",
    "multer-s3": "^2.9.0",
    "node-geocoder": "^3.27.0",
    "nodemailer": "^6.4.11",
    "pug": "2.0.0-beta11",
    "redis": "^3.0.2",
    "socket.io": "^2.3.0",
    "striptags": "^3.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.2",
    "stripe": "^8.102.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: There is no limit on the number of packages you can install.

Comment: I am going to switch to yarn, apparently this is a bug npm has had for years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NPM has had this issue for years. Yarn seems to be a good alternative.